# Generate test cases (use case scenarios) from use case

Tags: uml, use-case, tool-uml

Is there any tool which can automatically extract all possible scenarios from an use case UML diagram?

Comment: You should post what tool you are using to create your diagrams.

Comment: MagicDraw, but the diagrams can be redone in any tool which has such a feature.

Comment: i search a lot but i didn't find any tool for this may be you can try XML spy schema editor

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think so.  The problem is that the Use Case diagram is almost entirely content free in UML.  It's really just a guide to how to read the use case body specifications and documents their relationships.  A test case generator would need to read the use case bodies, however UML doesn't define a standard form or semantics for them, so there's nothing for a test case generator to work with.